Prepotential in 5d $\mathcal{N}=1$ with higher-derivative correction
The (bosonic part of the) action of five-dimensional $\mathcal{N}=1$ supergravity coupled to a number of vector multiplets reads
$$S=\frac{1}{2\kappa_5^2}\int\star(R-\frac{1}{2}h_{ij}(\phi)\partial-\mu\phi^i\partial^\mu\phi^j)-\frac{1}{2}\int a_{IJ}(\phi)F^I\wedge\star F^J+\frac{1}{6(2\pi)^2}\int C_{IJK}A^I\wedge F^J\wedge F^K.$$
Due to its relation to four-dimensional $\mathcal{N}=2$ supergravity, the Coulomb branch of the moduli space (spanned by the vacuum expectation values of the $\phi^i$) satisfies special geometry. In other words, there exists a holomorphic prepotential
$$\mathcal{F}=\frac{1}{6}C_{IJK}Y^I(\phi)Y^J(\phi)Y^K(\phi)$$
in terms of which the moduli space is given by $\mathcal{F}=1$ and all quantities in the above action can be derived from this prepotential.
My question is about the higher-derivative correction
$$S_{ARR}=\frac{1}{96}\int C_IA^I\wedge\mathrm{tr}(R\wedge R).$$
Does the theory with this term included still satisfy special geometry, i.e.
is there a (maybe even systematic) way to compute a prepotential, say $\widetilde{\mathcal{F}}$, that captures the $C_I$ as well?
Any hints are very welcome!

The correction $S_{ARR}$ gives rise to a modified special geometry constraint
$$\mathcal{F}=1-\frac{C_I}{72}\left(D Y^I+ F^{I\,\mu\nu}v_{\mu\nu}\right),$$
where $D$ and $v_{\mu\nu}$ are auxiliary fields that can be integrated out to find the on-shell action.
This is done explicitly in the paper "Black holes in five-dimensional gauged supergravity with higher derivatives" [arXiv:0812.3572 [hep-th]] by Sera
Cremonin et al.
